# Javascript arraybuffer to file in Django

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, arraybuffer

people!
I have tried to send via  HTTP POST (using AngularJS) the content of a file (images to be more precise) converted in ArrayBuffer (UInt8) to a Django server but I cannot manage to save it correctly in file on the server.

Javascript code:

```
filesToUpload = document.getElementById('files')
  var files = filesToUpload.files;
  for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
  {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(fileToBeUploaded) {
        return function(e) {
            var fileContent = e.target.result;
            var bin = new Uint8Array(fileContent);
            console.log(bin);
            var request = $http({
                    url: urlAddImagesRestaurant,
                    method: "post",
                    data: {
                      fileStructure: fileToBeUploaded,
                      datafile: bin
                    }
                }); 
              return request.then( service.handleSuccess, service.handleError ); 
        };
    })(files[i]);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[i]);
  }
}
```

Has someone any idea how to save the content of the arraybuffer in django?

Comment: What are you doing on the django side? And what do you mean by "cannot manage to save it correctly in file on the server"?

Comment: Are you trying to upload the same file twice? `fileToBeUploaded` is the file and `bin` is the file in a byte array. Also why don't you just use a FormData object to upload the file(s)?

Comment: @aus_lacy I iterate on the dictionary and write the bits (using the chr function) on the new file, however it does not save properly the file.

no , Musa, the filesToUpload = document.getElementById('files') can be more than one file to be upload. Is there a great difference between FileReader and the FormData in this case?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to write the images as UInt8 array buffer? Why not just create a file upload form with Django and use Angular for the HTTP request to upload the entire file?

Comment: With a FormData object the back end would be exactly the same as if you uploaded the file with a regular html form.

Comment: @aus_lacy : The problem is that I can't use django on the templates because we want to use PhoneGap to make a mobile app with the templates, that being said the front-end can only connect with the Django server via http requests.
However I didn't used FormData yet would it solve the problem, Musa?